# Apache2 userdir enabled, but still have no access

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I am trying to set up an apache server on my Kubuntu 13.04 laptop. I have installed the apache2 package and `sudo a2enmod userdir; sudo service apache2 restart`, but still when I visit `http://localhost/~user`, it says something like this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~user on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Result of `tail /var/log/apache2/access.log`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:16:22:01 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:16:22:02 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:17:35:30 +0200] "GET /~kaiyin HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:17:35:30 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:17:35:30 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:17:36:26 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:17:36:26 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:21:05:17 +0200] "GET /~kaiyin HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:21:05:17 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Aug/2013:21:05:17 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Result of `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Fri Aug 02 21:05:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:05:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:06:59 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~kaiyin denied
[Fri Aug 02 21:06:59 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:06:59 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:07:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~kaiyin denied
[Fri Aug 02 21:07:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Aug 02 21:07:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Do you have a `public_html` directory for the user? Does the user running apache have permission to read it?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I have set it to 755, also tried 777.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `public_html` directories need to have their permissions like this so that the user that Apache is running as can access it:

```
$ chmod -R 755 ~/public_html
```

#### still not work?

If you look in your Apache error logs you might see a line like this:

> [Fri Aug 02 21:06:59 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /~kaiyin denied

This is telling you that Apache doesn't have permissions to navigate to your user's directory (~kaiyin) in this example.

How to fix this?

You need to make sure that read + execute bits are set for either a group that Apache is a member of or the others read + execute bits are set on the user's directory as well so that Apache can access the `public_html` folder down below.

#### Example

```
/home
|-- [drwxr-x---]  /home/sam

/home/sam
|-- [drwxr-xr-x]  /home/sam/public_html
```

#### References

- [How can I make a public HTML folder in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526742/how-can-i-make-a-public-html-folder-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I have already done that, but I still got a 403 forbidden.

Comment: @CravingSpirit - tail the apache logs (`/var/log/httpd/access.log`) and (`/var/log/httpd/error.log`) to see if there are any additional messages.

Comment: I have added the log to the post.

Comment: @CravingSpirit - notice the access denied on the ~kaiyin`? Apache's user doesn't have access to the top level directories of the users. You need read + execute rights so that it can access them.

Comment: Does that dir even exist? Is it just my home dir?

Comment: My home dir is set to 700, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @CravingSpirit - yup!!! Apache needs read + execute rights through the entire directory tree, not just at the leaf nodes.

Comment: Wow, indeed, 755 solves it!

Comment: @CravingSpirit - devils in the details 8-)

Comment: @CravingSpirit - updated.

Comment: Actually, you almost certainly don't need 755; 711 or even 710 group www-data should do on the parents of `public_html`; it will do on public_html too if you don't need file listings, otherwise Apache will need read too (so 755/750 rather than 711/710).

Comment: @slm I'm getting the same error, but I've already verified that the entire stack from my home directory down has `755`; what am I missing here? Must there be a `public_html` folder as well? So if my `Directory` points to `/Users/myuser/Sites`, do I then need a `public_html` folder inside of `Sites`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - you have a new Q, ask it on the site. I'd need to see specifics to render any type of help.

Comment: I wouldnt `chmod -R 0755 public_html` that will get the files too, and you really want a permission that allows access by the user and the server only. I added the server group to the user and set 0750. However your second comment about httpd cant navigate solved for me. Id vote up if it wasnt for the bad advise to recursively 0755 all files n folders.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
UserDir public_html
UserDir disabled root

  <Directory /home/*/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
      # Apache <= 2.2:
      #Order allow,deny
      #Allow from all

      # Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
      # Apache <= 2.2:
      #Order deny,allow
      #Deny from all

      # Apache >= 2.4:
      Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have the correct settings in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`. I was getting permission denied after chmodding my public_html and then decided to check the `userdir.conf`. I noticed there was settings for earlier apache versions, as well as newer.  I knew I was running the latest so enabled the newer settings and now all is working fine

Comment: Thank you for including the the Apache <=2.2 info, that's why it wasn't working for me and is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `/etc/hosts` file to eliminate the need of temporary URL. If there is reference for the complete URL in theme or plugin (if you have any) the site won't show up the contents in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a folder does not have search(`x`) permissions or a file does don't have read(`r`) permissions

`namei -ml /home/joe/public_html/index.html`

```
f: /home/joe/public_html/index.html
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  home
drwxr-x--- joe joe joe
drwxrwxr-x joe joe public_html
-rwxr-xr-x joe joe index.html
```

Apache needs to search and read all folders from the root (`/`) till `index.html` (ie must have `r` & `x` permissions). If you notice from the above, `/home/joe` does NOT allow `other` users to read (`r`) or search (`x`).

## Solution 1:

Add the apache2 user (in my case `www-data`), to the logged in user group. This way `www-data` has access to everything user `/home/joe`.

In my case apache2 run under the user named `www-data`. So we need to add `www-data` user into the group `joe`

`adduser www-data joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must have `rx` permissions for the group.

`chmod -R g+rw /home/joe/public_html`

This is less secure as any file under `/home/joe` can be accessed by the apache server. If apache2 admin accidentally changes the configuration to access `some_private_folder` instead of `public_html`, others can easily access these.

## Solution 2:

Allow any `other` to search(`x`) `/home/joe`

`chmod o+x /home/joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must be accessible by `others` for `rx` permissions.

`chmod -R o+rw /home/joe/public_html`